# Mobile payments with paypal

Tags: android, node.js, paypal

I'm integrating mobile payments with Paypal. I just have one question.

I'm thinking about two posible implementations:

1) Using Android SDK to make payments with Paypal and after confirmation, put the data to the server
2) Make Paypal communication via server side. When an user wants to buy through android app, it will ask the server to do it. After that, server responds with the appropiate answer.

I think I'm chosing the second one, but, any advices?

Also, server is being developed with node.js. Any advices of how to handle paypal payments? I've seen paynode (https://github.com/jamescarr/paynode) but I don't know if its the right choice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a native app, you should use #1 (the new SDK at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK). If you're building a mobile webapp, you must do #2. You could build a native app with and have the server create the payment, but you'll still need to present a PayPal hosted webview to authenticate the user.

Note that even with #1, you'll still need to build a server-side component to verify that the payment was received by PayPal.